# Get SAPUI5 router object in separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, routes, sapui5, router

I created an HTML5 application on the SAP Cloud platform using the MVC pattern.
Inside the index.html file, there is a javascript file reference added in the  section. In this JS file, I want to get access to the router of the application, to steer the application from an external source (using web sockets). This file will contain all the logic to process the incoming push message and navigate to the desired page.

I'm struggling to get the router object inside this file to navigate, is there any way to get the router object from the sap core,... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by registering the router in the component.js file and then accessing it in the other file :)

-Component.js

```html
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/UIComponent"
], function (UIComponent) {
   "use strict";
   return UIComponent.extend("be.myapp.Component", {
      metadata : {
            manifest: "json"
      },
      init : function () {
  // call the init function of the parent
  UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
         
  var router = this.getRouter();
  this.routeHandler = new sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler(router);
  router.register("appRouter");  // Assign a name to Router, so that we can access it in all controllers by using this name  
  router.initialize(); // Initialise the Router  
         
      }
   });
});
```

```html
var oRouter = sap.ui.core.routing.Router.getRouter("appRouter");
oRouter.navTo("overview", {}, true);
```